# Heroku git:clone has caused problems

Tags: git, github, heroku, push

I am using Heroku to host my application. I have a local folder on my desktop in which I have been working in, then using `git push heroku master` to push my changes to the server.

I used `git clone` by mistake and it created another folder in my directory (I think its done something else).

I deleted it and used `git add .`

When I done this it has staged *all* my files ready to commit:

```
modified: index.php
modified: login.php
modified: register.php

etc etc etc for hundreds of files...
```

I am scared to commit and push in case it mucks up my app.

Why has it done this? And is it safe to commit?

```
git diff --stat --cached heroku/master
```

outputs

```
 .DS_Store                                  | Bin
 Procfile                                   |   0
 app/.DS_Store                              | Bin
 app/README.md                              |   0
 app/config.php                             |   0
```

all the way down all my files until

```
 vendor/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/support/build/_conf/php/php.ini  |0
:
```

then

```
git diff --cached
```

outputs

```
diff --git a/latest.dump b/latest.dump
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..b4d47cf
Binary files /dev/null and b/latest.dump differ
diff --git a/output.sql b/output.sql
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..62320e0
--- /dev/null
+++ b/output.sql
@@ -0,0 +1,141 @@
+--
+-- PostgreSQL database dump
+--
```

more database operations on my database etc

```
git diff --cached heroku/master
```

shows

```
diff --git a/app/phq-9.php b/app/reg.php
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/app/preferences.php b/app/login.php
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/app/question_style.css b/app/style.css
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/app/script.js b/app/script.js
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/app/sleep_diary.php b/app/diary.php
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/app/stylesheet.css b/app/stylesheet.css
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/composer.json b/composer.json
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/composer.lock b/composer.lock
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
diff --git a/latest.dump b/latest.dump
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..b4d47cf
Binary files /dev/null and b/latest.dump differ
:
```

Comment: What does `git diff --cached` show?

Comment: @Chris updated it

Comment: The new files are simply new files. The other command doesn't help much. What does `git diff --cached` (_without_ `--stat`) show for files that aren't new?

Comment: @Chris updated again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `database.dump` file is a new file. You probably don't want to include that in your repository (data rarely belongs there) but I don't know enough about your application to say for sure.

As for the rest of your staged changes, `git diff --cached` shows that the files have been made executable:

```
diff --git a/app/phq-9.php b/app/reg.php
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Git only tracks one file permission bit: the executable bit. Files are either 644 (owner read/write, group and other read-only) or 755 (owner read/write/execute, group and other read/execute).

If this is something you want you can commit the changes. If it isn't you can discard them. Personally, I'd go through the output very carefully to make sure I know what I'm discarding.

I'm not sure why your files became executable. Nothing in your question looks like it would have caused that to happen.

Comment: Thanks, thats helped. What does it mean that my files are executable?

Comment: @codeman, it literally means that they can be executed (run) directly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix). For example, if you try to run `app/ph1-9.php` when your files aren't executable your operating system will give you an error. You need to run something like `php app/ph1-9.php` instead, providing the filename as an argument to the `php` program. If they are executable your operating system will let you run `app/ph1-9.php` (though you'll probably need a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in that case).